# Accordion Menu PlusMinus change FontAwesome - Change Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I want to change the PlusMinus which is added by text to -> [FontAwesome Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). Would need some help with it.

The Code for Plus

```
$(".plusminus").text('+');
```

That for Minus

```
checkElement.parent().find(".plusminus").text("-");
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5abCc/2/)

Comment: What exactly is your question. As I looked at it, it worked. Not on load but after some clicking it was working and displaying the plus and minus correctly. Please be more precise what your problem is.

Comment: I want to change the Class Name of plusminus to another one if Menu is Open and change to another Class Name if is closed. At the moment the Javascript just add "+" or "-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add fontawesome as reference and change your simple text `+` or `-` to the plus-minus icons using FontAwesome rules, like:

```
var content = '<span class="cnt">' + count + '</span><span class="plusminus"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>';
```

and

```
checkElement.parent().find(".plusminus").html("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
```

Demo using FontAwesome 4.0.3 : http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/779R7/

Ref: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not solved. Check at loading the Page the state of Plus Minus. The opened one has a Plus too.. http://jsfiddle.net/779R7/4/

Comment: @user3005380 the question is solved, but your starting fiddle was buggy too...when I have a minute I'll take a look

Comment: Ohh.. Sorry you are right. How can I solve that? Would be happy for your reply.

Comment: @MK. I was writing the same solution ;-D

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward You did beat me to the answer  ;) +1 from me